# Filtering with React Sortable Tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filtering, reduce

I'm using react sortable tree and want to be able to filter. I'm getting the filtered nodes from our backend server then doing a reduce on the current tree to display filtered nodes. This part work fine but when I fetch children my tree state gets messed up and I suspect it could be due to javascript references.

Code below:
FilteredNodes is from server

```
static filterNodes = (map, processingStatuses, filteredNodes) => (newTree, node) => {
    const docNode = cloneDeep(TreeUtils.docNodeFromTreeNode(map, node));
    const thisNodePasses = filteredNodes.findIndex(findNode => findNode.id === docNode.id);
    if (thisNodePasses >= 0) {
      newTree.push({ ...node });
      return newTree;
    }

    if (docNode.children && docNode.children.length) {
      const filteredChildren = docNode.children.reduce(
        FilterUtils.filterNodes(map, processingStatuses, filteredNodes),
        [],
      );
      if (filteredChildren.length) {
        newTree.push({
          ...node,
          children: [...filteredChildren],
        });
      }
    }

    return newTree;
  }
```

```
  static getFilteredTree = (tree, map, processingStatuses, filteredNodes) => {

    return filteredNodes.length ?
      tree.reduce(FilterUtils.filterNodes(map, processingStatuses, filteredNodes), []) : tree;
  }
```

How should I be handling filtering?